# Is there more than one Q-matrix update formula?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python, q-learning

I asked a question a while ago here and since then I've been solving the issues within my code but I have just one question... This is the formula for updating the Q-Matrix in Q-Learning:

$$Q(s_t, a_t) = Q(s_t, a_t) + \alpha \times (R+Q(s_{t+1}, max_a)-Q(s_t, a_t))$$

However, I saw a Q-Learning example that uses a different formula, which I'm applying to my own problem and I'm getting good results:

$$Q(s_t, a_t) = R(s_t,a_t) + \alpha \times Q(s_{t+1}, max_a)$$

Is this valid?

Comment: Where did you see the second implementation?  Perhaps there is a context being missed.

Comment: @SeeDerekEngineer it was to solve the basic problem where there's 7 nodes and you wanna go from 2 to 5 or something equivalent. Does that make it different?

Answer (score 3):

No, your second statement does not correctly implement the Q-learning update rule, which the first statement correctly implements.

Answer (score 1):

Your second code snippet is equivalent to this:

$$Q_{k+1}(s,a)  \leftarrow r + \alpha \text{max}_{a'} Q_k(s', a')$$

This looks like a simplified Value Iteration update to me, where you have incorrectly switched $\alpha$ (the learning rate) for $\gamma$ (the discount rate).

The full Value Iteration update based on action values looks like this:

$$Q_{k+1}(s,a)  \leftarrow \sum_{r,s'} p(r,s'|s,a)(r + \gamma \text{max}_{a'} Q_k(s', a'))$$

This is almost the same as your equation when you have a deterministic environment (so you can directly predict single values $r$ and $s'$ from $s, a$)

As such, it will sort of work with certain assumptions:

- You want a specific discount rate, or don't particularly care about predicting values, just finding a close-to-optimal policy
- The environment is deterministic

The further away you are from those assumptions, the worse fit the simpler update method will be to your problem. It is definitely not Q-learning either way.

Comment: Oh, ok. Not sure why they use this formula in the example though. Either way, don't understand why I get good results using this formula but the actually correct one doesn't work! Guess I'll have to keep trying to find out some more, thanks!

Comment: @Sergio Maybe you're not using the correct variables when indexing or somewhere else. It would have been better to ask a specific question with your code (maybe on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)).

Comment: @nbro and Neil: I was using a discount factor of 1 the whole time, is that bad? I just changed it to 0.1 and now I'm getting very good results with the actual Q-Learning formula. Guess I was missing that detail.

Comment: @Sergio A discount factor of 1 means that you're valuing the future rewards in the same way that you're valuing the immediate reward (the one you received after having taken the action at the current step). You often don't want this behaviour, in general, because, intuitively, the future is uncertain, so you want to give less weight to those future rewards. See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/221402/82135.

Comment: @Sergio A discount factor of $0.1$ seems awefully low though. Much more common choices are like... $\gamma = 0.99$ or $\gamma = 0.9$.

Comment: I think he's mixing up discount factor with step size parameter

Comment: @DennisSoemers Apologies for the late answer. I tried 0.9 and it works well too. I'm new to Reinforcement Learning, so I'm still trying to get to grips with it! Thanks for the help, appreciate it. Is 0.1 _wrong_ though, or just an uncommon choice? It just means I'm giving less emphasis to future rewards so, for example, if it returns better results, would it not be better to use that?

Comment: @Sergio It's not necessarily *wrong*... in theory, anything that is between $0$ and $1$ is fine. It's so low though that you get very close to only caring about immediate one-step rewards, and almost ignore any future rewards (even if they're very close in the future, only a couple of steps away). But yeah sure, if it works, it works.